# Getting all windows using UISpec4J

Tags: java, swing, uispec4j

I am trying to use [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org/) in order to automate a Java Swing application. After adapter setup:

```
setAdapter(new MainClassAdapter(Main.class, new String[0]));
```

I am trying to obtain the main window:

```
Window mainWindow = getMainWindow();
```

Instead of a login dialog, I am getting a splash screen with logo of application. All my attempts to call this dialog manually have failed.

How can I get the list of opened dialogs/windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `MainClassAdapter` is not designed to handle a sequence of windows. However you can implement your own adapter that ignores the splash screen and returns the subsequent window. Here is a sample taken from UISpec4J [forums](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/uispec4j/message/430):

```
setAdapter(new UISpecAdapter() {
    public Window getMainWindow() {
        final Window[] result = new Window[1];
        WindowInterceptor.init(new MainClassTrigger(Main.class, new String[0]))
            .processTransientWindow()
            .process(new WindowHandler() {
                public Trigger process(Window window) throws Exception {
                result[0] = window;
                return Trigger.DO_NOTHING;
                }
            })
        .run();
        return result[0];
    }
});
```